# angular-moment-picker directive updates unbind model

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I was using angular-moment-picker for datepickers. This is how I used it:

```
<form name="frm">
<div class="input-group" moment-picker="item.answer"
     change="onInput(frm.inputDT.$valid, true, item.fields)">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <input name ="inputDT" class="form-control" data-ng-model="item.answer" />
</div>
</form>
```

`<form name="FORMB">
    <input name="qTxt" class="form-control" type="text" data-ng model="field.answer"/>
</form>`

Unfortunately the datepicker updates to 'field.Answer' model though the form is not using the directive. Whenever I input any number into the textbox (ie:3) it will be changed automatically to date format ( 03.12.2016 ). As I debugged it I wonder why angular-moment-picker.js watcher was executed.